# Facebook plugin does not work with phonegap build

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am having problems correctly setting up the Facebook plugin with PhoneGap build.
I have tried many things, but I couldn't fix the problem.

My config.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.bliphead.spottma"
        version="1.0.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

    <name>Spottma</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        Bliphead
    </author>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.3.2">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="MYAPPID" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="bit_spotted_test" />
    </gap:plugin>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

I removed some settings to shorten the code. 
I'm loading all scripts in my index.htm

```html
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<script src="facebook_js_sdk.js"></script>

// Device ready
FB.init({
  appId: 'APPID', // I have replaced it in my working code. Same for the config.xml.
  nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
  useCachedDialogs: false
});
```

If I want to initialize the Facebook SDK with `FB.init`, I get the error that FB is undefined.

Maybe the solution is trivial, but I searched way too long and didn't find a working solution.

Comment: I thought I just have to include: cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js and facebook_js_sdk.js. Now I had included the facebook sdk from the facebook cdn and I get no error but it doesn't perfom an login...

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use a plugin that does not support Phonegap Build 3.0. Currently, that plugin only supports versions 2.5.0, 2.7.0, 2.9.0. You can set the version of Phonegap Build in your config.xml by using `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.0.0" />`. By not using that tag at all, it assumes you want the latest version of Phonegap Build, which is currently 3.0.

Comment: Hey Dom, thanks for your answer. But I am using 2.9.0. Here you can find my complete config file: https://gist.github.com/panquish/6881333

Comment: Anyone solved this issue yet, i have  <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="2.9.0" /> but phonegap build still fails